# Eddy currents induced throughout the volume of the material or only the surface?

Tags: electromagnetism

If a conductive slab has induced Eddy currents to oppose the change in magnetic flux, is the induced current uniformly distributed throughout the slab's volume or only at the surface? I might have confused myself with a room temperate copper vs. superconductor.

Comment: That depends on the ratio between skin depth and slab dimensions. If the skin depth is small compared to the dimensions, the currents will be mostly near the surface, otherwise a (weak) current might be induced almost homogeneously in the volume.

Comment: All electrons travel on the surface

Answer (score 1):

Practically, it cannot remain uniform due to the skin effect (even assuming a uniform material, a uniform magnetic field). You will have a depth which calculates as:

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/503e00af2636a217d5c8be7d58ffce4a50e088dc